# Pre-allocate an array of structures for use in genetic algorithm in Matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, structure

This is the code I have so far:

```
population = 50
individual = repmat(struct('genes',[], 'fitness', 0), population, 1);
```

So what I'm doing is creating a population of 50 individuals these individuals each have the component genes and fitness. What I can't seem to do correctly is set genes up to be a 50 cell array rather than just a single cell.

Can anyone shed some light on this for me please?

A further addition I'd like to make is to populate the genes array with random values (either 0 or 1). I imagine I could easily do this afterwards by iterating through the genes array of each member and using what ever random number generating functionality Matlab has available. However it would be more efficient to do when the structures are being pre-allocated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking to allocate different random values to each individual, then doing a repmat as an allocation isn't going to help, as this just replicates the same thing 50 times. You are better off just using a simple loop:

```
population=50;
individual=struct('genes',[],'fitness',0);
for m=1:50
    individual(m).genes=rand(1,50)>=0.5;
end
```

This is no less efficient than allocating all of them and then looping through - in each case the genes array is only allocated once. Moreover, allocating and reallocating 50 cells isn't going to be very slow - you will probably not notice much difference until you hit thousands or tens of thousands.

Comment: Thank you very much. This has helped massively.

Answer (score 2):

Why not use a class instead of a struct?  Creating a simple class `person`:

```
classdef person
    properties
        fitness = 0;
    end
    properties(SetAccess = private)
        genes
    end
    methods
        function obj = person()
            obj.genes = randi([0 1], 10, 1);
        end
    end
end
```

and then running the following script:

```
population = 50;

people = person.empty(population, 0);
people(1).fitness = 100;
people(2).fitness = 50;

people(1)
people(2)
```

produces the following console output:

```
ans = 

  person with properties:

    fitness: 100
      genes: [10x1 double]


ans = 

  person with properties:

    fitness: 50
      genes: [10x1 double]
```

Comment: +1: Objects would be my choice as well: nice, self-contained, manageable things that keep the complexity away from the higher levels

Answer (score 1):

Well, keeping to structs, here's a few ways:

```
% Your original method
clear all
tic
population = 50;
individual = repmat(struct('genes', false(50,1), 'fitness', 0), population, 1);
toc

% simple loop
clear all
tic
population = 50;
individual(population,1) = struct('genes', false(50,1), 'fitness', 0);
for ii = 1:population
    individual(ii).genes = false(50,1);
end
toc

% Third option
clear all
tic
population = 50;
individual = struct(...
    'genes'  , num2cell(false(50,population),2), ...
    'fitness', num2cell(zeros(population,1)));
toc
```

Results:

```
Elapsed time is 0.009887 seconds.  % your method
Elapsed time is 0.000475 seconds.  % loop
Elapsed time is 0.013252 seconds.  % init with cells
```

My suggestion: just use the loop :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do something similar to this :

```
individual = repmat(struct('genes',{cell(1,50)}, 'fitness', 0), population, 1);
```